# Why is vitali caratheodory theorem important?

Tags: real-analysis, approximation, semicontinuous-functions

The Vitali Caratheodory theorem, as stated in Rudin's real and complex analysis, states that for nice measures $\mu$ we can approximate any $L^{1}$ function $f$ by upper lower semicontinuous $u$ and lower semicontinuous $v$ such that $u\leq f\leq v$ and

$$\int_{X} (u-v)d\mu < \epsilon$$.

I don't see why is this theorem important? Why would we want to approximate by upper and lower semicontinuous functions?

Comment: Seems similar in character to Lusin's theorem but somehow not as good.

Comment: Well, you can't do this for continuous functions, and semicontinuous functions are just a slight generalization away from continuous functions when you consider the properly increasing classes of Baire 1 functions, Baire 2 functions, $\ldots,$ Baire $\omega$ functions, Baire $\omega + 1$ functions, Baire $2 \omega$ functions, Baire $2 \omega$ + 1 functions, $\ldots$, $\ldots$, $\ldots$, Baire ${\omega}^{\omega}$ functions, $\ldots$, $\ldots$, $\ldots$ --- $\omega_1$ many classes (for Borel measurable functions), and there's still a ways to go to get to Lebesgue measurable functions.

Comment: See also this google search for [semicontinuous + "in between theorem"](https://www.google.com/search?q=semicontinuous+%22in+between+theorem%22).

Answer (score 0):

An important application of this theorem is the fundamental theorem of calculus for the Lebesgue integral (see Theorem 7.21, p.149 Rudin's Real and Complex Analysis).

Also see J. J. Koliha. A Fundamental Theorem of Calculus for Lebesgue Integration. Amer. Math. Monthly, 113(6):551–555, 2006.